# serialize an object similar to $.param but do not call contained methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an object that I would like to serialize, however the object contains non-idempotent methods. Is there a built in jQuery method to handle this, or do I need to build something custom?

This question will actually answer [$resource update method behaving strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779574/resource-update-method-behaving-strangely) which has become so bloated I felt it might be worth opening a new question since the solution may come in useful outside of the scope of the original question.

**UPDATE**:

To clarify, I have the following object as output from console.log:

```
Resource {$get: function, $save: function, $query: function, $remove: function, $delete: function…}
id: 1
name: "tits"
__proto__: Resource
$delete: function (a1, a2, a3) {
$get: function (a1, a2, a3) {
$query: function (a1, a2, a3) {
$remove: function (a1, a2, a3) {
$save: function (a1, a2, a3) {
$update: function (a1, a2, a3) {
```

So when I pass it through $.param(), all the methods on the object are triggered as part of the serialization process. Instead, I would only like to serialize the properties of the object which do not trigger any other methods.

Comment: Are you trying to serialize the methods? Could you give a code example?

Comment: No i don't want to serialize them, I want to ignore them, I'll update the OP